# pass parameter in g:remoteLink as result of javascript function

Tags: javascript, grails

in .gsp file i have javaScript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getCurrentItemNumber(){
        return document.getElementById('item_itemNumber').innerHTML.substr(6);
    }
</script>
```

and in g:remoteLink I like to pass param using that function

something like following ...

```
<g:remoteLink id="remove_item_button" action="removeItem" update="itemBox"
            params="[itemNumber:getCurrentItemNumber()]">- Remove Item</g:remoteLink>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS workaround I can suggest following

1. change g:remoteLink  to simple link

   "<"a id="remove_item_button" class="btn small primary" onclick="removeItem();">- Remove Item "<"/a>
2. Add javaScript function which will submit data via AJAX

   function removeItem() {
           $.ajax({type:'POST',
               data:{**'itemNumber':getCurrentItemNumber()**},
               url:'${createLink(action: 'removeItem')}',
               success:function (data, textStatus) {
                   jQuery('#itemBox').html(data);
               }});
       }