# Pass Javascript Variable into grails RemoteFunction

Tags: javascript, dom, grails, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass parameter in g:remoteLink as result of javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023672/pass-parameter-in-gremotelink-as-result-of-javascript-function)

I am trying to call a remoteFunction call that is triggered by an onclick for a button, but the click does not call the function. I have tested the onlick command with an alert startment and the function is called. here is my code.

```
<input type="button" onclick="exportList()" value= "Export"/>

function exportList(){

            var profile= document.getElementById('dropdown').value
            ${remoteFunction(controller: 'profile' , action:'export', params: "'profile=' + profile")}  


}
```

When I take out the parameter and the var profile, the function is STILL not called... My controller and action are properly named so I do not know why I am having this error. Thanks in advance if you can help!

Comment: same with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023672/pass-parameter-in-gremotelink-as-result-of-javascript-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JoeCortopassi is correct - you can't just use the grails construct of `${remoteFunction...}` directly in javascript.  I've done this using Jquery like this:

```
function exportList() {
    var profileToUse = document.getElementById('dropdown').value
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/youApp/profile/export",
        type: "POST",
        data: {profile: profileToUse}
    });
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. I just wasn't familiar with Grails, thanks @Kelly

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what this is supposed to do, but it looks poorly formed

```
${remoteFunction(controller: 'profile' , action:'export', params: "'profile=' + profile")}
```

are you sure you want to say `var{remoteFunction()}`? Cause `$` is just a variable. Makes even less sense if you are using jQuery. Also, what you are passing `remoteFunction()` looks like it was supposed to be object, but isn't wrapped in `{}`

Comment: edited for another idea @daniellanger

Comment: I dont understand what you are proposing

Comment: Trying to say that the ${remoteFunction(... part does not look like proper javascript